# Ejecutar en un fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, imagen

Buenas, tengo el siguiente código y quisiera saber si se puede modificar para ser ejecutado desde un fragment, el asunto es que hay partes que no se como modificar y que se me ponen en rojo en el android studio

Este es el codigo:

```
private void captureImageInitialization() {
    /**
     * a selector dialog to display two image source options, from camera
     * ‘Take from camera’ and from existing files ‘Select from gallery’
     */
    final String[] items = new String[] { "Tomar desde la cámara",
            "Seleccionar de la galeria" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Seleccione la imagen");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
            // camera
            if (item == 0) {
                /**
                 * To take a photo from camera, pass intent action
                 * ‘MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE‘ to open the camera app.
                 */
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                /**
                 * Also specify the Uri to save the image on specified path
                 * and file name. Note that this Uri variable also used by
                 * gallery app to hold the selected image path.
                 */
                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg"));

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        mImageCaptureUri);

                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // pick from file
                /**
                 * To select an image from existing files, use
                 * Intent.createChooser to open image chooser. Android will
                 * automatically display a list of supported applications,
                 * such as image gallery or file manager.
                 */
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}

public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions = options;

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon))
                    .setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name))
                    .setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class CropOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            /**
             * After taking a picture, do the crop
             */
            doCrop();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            /**
             * After selecting image from files, save the selected path
             */
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

            doCrop();

            break;

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            /**
             * After cropping the image, get the bitmap of the cropped image and
             * display it on imageview.
             */
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                //Uri imageUri = extras.getParcelable("data");
                profilePicture = photo;
                iv_profile.setImageBitmap(photo);
                IMAGE_STATUS = true;




            }

            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
            /**
             * Delete the temporary image
             */
            if (f.exists())
                f.delete();

            break;

    }
}

private void doCrop() {
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();
    /**
     * Open image crop app by starting an intent
     * ‘com.android.camera.action.CROP‘.
     */
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    /**
     * Check if there is image cropper app installed.
     */
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    /**
     * If there is no image cropper app, display warning message
     */
    if (size == 0) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        /**
         * Specify the image path, crop dimension and scale
         */
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        /**
         * There is posibility when more than one image cropper app exist,
         * so we have to check for it first. If there is only one app, open
         * then app.
         */

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                    res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            /**
             * If there are several app exist, create a custom chooser to
             * let user selects the app.
             */
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent
                        .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                    CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });

            builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null,
                                null);
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Esta es una de las partes donde se me pone en rojo:

```
 List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent, 0);
```

En esta parte al cambiar "Registro" por el nombre de la clase genera un error, la clase es un fragment, y no tengo idea de que comando usar

```
  for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final Registro.CropOption co = new Registro.CropOption();

                co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent
                        .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
```

Las partes que estan en rojo me dicen que no se puede resolver el metodo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo [`getPackageManager()`pertenece al Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager()) y un `Fragment` no es un Context, por lo que no encuentra el metodo.

Tienes que obtener el `Activity`(que es un Context) del `Fragment` con el método `getActivity()` y luego obtener el `getPackgeManaget()`:

```
List<ResolveInfo> list = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent, 0);
```

Comment: Ok, eso ya lo hice y se supone que esa parte esta bien, el asunto ahora es en la ultima parte del codigo en la que hago lo siguiente: final Registro.CropOption co = new Registro.CropOption(); esa parte sigue arrojandome error